# HTML to PDF Convert in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Want to convert HTML to PDF in PHP.

```
 $pdf = $quotingTool->createPdf($record->get('content'), $record- 
 >get('header'), $record->get('footer'), $fileName);
 when use this createPdf() function then in this function use mpdf.

public function createPdf($content, $header = '', $footer = '', $name, $path 
= 'storage/QuotingTool/', $styles = array(), $scripts = array(), $escapeForm = true)
{

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
    echo $content; //It shows proper designed html.
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $fullFileName = $path . $name;
    $mpdf->Output($fullFileName, 'I');
    return $fullFileName;
 }

$fileContent = '';
    if(is_readable($pdf)) {
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($pdf);
    }
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: private');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . html_entity_decode($fileName, ENT_QUOTES, vglobal('default_charset')));
    header('Content-Description: PHP Generated Data');
    echo $fileContent;
```

Here in `$content` shows proper html, but when it goes to `$mpdf->WriteHTML($content)`, after generating pdf, the design is not showing properly.Contents goes misplaced!

Comment: mPdf has some limitations and https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html check this link for supported css

Answer (score 1):

Well due to insufficient code i am not able to know which class are you using 
besides,you can use [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) read the discription there